# scrbook class leads to bitmap font but bookclss doesn't

Tags: fonts, koma-script, scrbook, typefaces, tex-gyre-math

I'd like to use the scrbook class and included the Gyre Heros font but for some reason does it not lead to the desired output (i.e. it quite different from the output that created by the book class) instead it seams to create an ugly bitmap font, why?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,                   
                         open=right,                
                         twoside = true,
                         a4paper,               
                         parskip=half,      
                         listof=totoc,      
                         fleqn,                 
                         ngerman,
                         headinclude=true,
                         footinclude=false,
                         captions=tableheading,
                         numbers=noenddot,
                         headings=big,
                         chapterprefix=false]   % 
                        {scrbook}  %vs book

 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}           % Wahl des Fonts, bzw.
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    % Zeichkodierung , Umlaute \usepackage{}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

%headings
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{
    \usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont} % "qhv" - TeX Gyre Heros, "b" - bold
    {} 
    {0em}
    {\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large \thesection\hspace{0.6em}}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge}
% % % % % % % % % % %


 \begin{document}
\onehalfspacing 
\chapter{Neues Kapitel}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Neue Section}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{Neue Section}
\blindtext[1]

\chapter{Neues Kapitel}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Neue Section}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{Neue Section}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{lmodern}` before `mathdesign` fixes it (altough the font is sightly different).

Comment: Probably because you do not have  the bitstream-charter font correctly installed.

Comment: Also, opposite to the standard class, KOMA-script use sans-serif font in the headings. If the body text looks OK, you can try `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`. If `charter` is installed, you will have that font in the headings too.

Comment: @Sveinung From the image, the bitmap fonts are the sans serif family.

Comment: If I compile that code, I get all type1 fonts. The headings are quite different from both of the examples posted. If you look in the output from LaTeX, you should see messages telling you if any fonts were not found and, at the end, a full list of the fonts which were used in the document.

Comment: Well, according to acrobat CharterBT and TexGyreHeros are Type1 fonts but there are F63 and F60 as Type3 font.  I use Miktex as Tex distribution do I have to (re)install some fonts? If yes, how could I do this?thx

Comment: You probably are running MiKTeX and didn't install the CM-Super fonts, so the sans serif is bitmapped. However, you should also do `\usepackage[scaled]{tgheros}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing things more complicated than they should be. The package `titlesec` shouldn't be used with KOMA-Script classes and `sectsty` is not to be used along with `titlesec` (nor with KOMA-Script classes).

If you want to change the appearance of the chapter header font, just do

```
\setkomafont{chapter}{<font specifications>}
```

In order that TeX Gyre Heros is used as the sans serif font, just do

```
\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}
```

In the example I omitted the irrelevant document class options.

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=12pt,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}    

\begin{document}

\chapter{Neues Kapitel}
\section{Neue Section}
\subsection{Neue Section}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether Helvetica matches Charter is a matter of opinion. I don't think they match.

Why did you get bitmapped fonts? Because you didn't set correctly the sans serif family document wide, but only locally in a couple of places. Moreover you're missing the CM-Super font package, so the default T1-encoded sans serif font is only available as bitmap.

Comment: Well, what font would you recommend for the headlines instead of Tex Gyre Heros ? Thanks for the tipp with cm-super.

Comment: @harryhaller Use `charter`in the headlines too.